# Is it possible to use GCM Cloud Connection Server (XMPP) with a Heroku app?

Tags: django, heroku, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging

We are developing a chat app for Android and our server is implemented in Django over Heroku. We have to choose now between the two possible connection servers that GCM gives you: HTTP or CCS (XMPP). We want to know if is it possible to use Heroku with the second choice.

https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have read so far about GCM, yes it is very possible. The Google servers are in charge of talking to the android app running on your users device, so no problems there.

The heroku hosted GCM XMPP Server is in charge of talking to the google servers. Inbound connections are limited to ports 80 and 443 on Heroku so as long as you only need to initiate and connect outbound from a heroku hosted python app to the google servers then you are fine.

From the Heroku Docs..

> Inbound requests are received by a load balancer that offers HTTP and
>   SSL termination. From here they are passed directly to a set of
>   routers.
>
> The routers are responsible for determining the location of your
>   application’s web dynos and forwarding the HTTP request to one of
>   these dynos.

I am happy to set up a test environment for you if you like to prove it.

You can also run a bash prompt to test things on heroku. just run `:/repofolder$ heroku run bash` from your prompt.

Here is a screenshot of heroku bash connected to gcm via port 5235

[image: Heroku bash telnet connect to gcm]

Comment: Looks good!, if you set up this test environment so we can be 100% sure that my Django app on Heroku will work with GCM you have my 300 points :)

Comment: It would be also be very important to know if the kind of implementation that we need to use the XMPP protocol to communicate with GCM can be implemented with Django. It seems like it would need a process running all the time and I am not sure that Django can work that way.

Comment: Yes it can. I've read in the documentation for gcm it is very friendly with Django. Also django has command line admin actions you can create. Your can run them with cron or constantly.

Comment: There is much documentation out there on how to use django with gcm, have a look through the source code on this repo for ideas on how to implement it in your specific app. https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm

Comment: Not sure how your app works but you can have a heroku worker process dyno running an admin action or any command you like from bash. Then you can also have a web dyno which might be a web front end to your django project.

Comment: The github repo you showed me: https://github.com/bogdal/django-gcm seems to be using the GCM HTTP connection, so it won't solve our doubts about how to implemente the GCM XMPP connection!

Comment: It seems we would have to use an additional dyno to run a Python App that makes the XMPP connection and flow control (as in https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html#flow)

Comment: We are looking for the most simple solution and not to incurring in any additional costs yet (1 dyno in Heroku is free, for 2 you start paying). It would be nice to have XMPP so we can get a confirmation receipt for each sent message, but we can live without it. Is it inevitable to use an additional dyno?? Can't it be integrated in the Django app and run from the web dyno?

What about the GCM HTTP connection? If we use this solution it looks like we could just integrate it in our Django app and therefore no need for additional Dynos, is this right?